# radio button selects form which contains radio button which selects form which contains radio button

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

Start returns radio buttons yes and no and Question 1, yes to Question 1 returns Questio1.1 and hides buttons, and so on.

The 'yes' buttons work like a charm, but I can't figure out how to make the 'no' buttons work as well

Thanks.

```
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='1' />I agree to start</div>

    <!-- Form 1-->

    <div class='content' id='content1'>
    <p>This is Question 1
    <br>'yes' will return Question 1.1y
    <br>'no' will return Question 1.1n</p>
    </div>
    <div class='info' id='info1'>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='2' />yes</div>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='6' />no</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form 1.1y-->

    <div class='content' id='content2'>
    <p>This is Question 1.1y
    <br>'yes' will return Question 1.1.1y
    <br>'no' will return Question 1.1.1n</p>
    </div>
    <div class='info' id='info2'>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='3' />yes</div>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='7' />no</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form 1.1.1y-->

    <div class='content' id='content3'>
    <p>This is Question 1.1.1y
    <br>'yes' will return answer_y
    <br>your 'no' will answer_n</p>
    </div>
    <div class='info' id='info3'>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='4' />yes</div>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='11' />no</div>
    </div>

    <!-- answer_y-->

    <div class='content' id='content4'>
    <div><p>answer_y</p></div>
    </div>

    <!-- answer_n-->

    <div class='content' id='content11'>
    <div><p>answer_n</p></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form 1.1n-->

    <div class='content' id='content6'>
    <p>This is Question 1.1n
    <br>'yes' will return Question 1.1.1y
    <br>'no' will return Question 1.1.1n</p>
    </div>
    <div class='info' id='info6'>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='9' />yes</div>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='10' />no</div>
    </div>


     <!-- Form 1.1.1n-->

    <div class='content' id='content10'>
    <p>This is Question 1.1.1n
    <br>'yes' will return answer_y
    <br>'no' will return answer_n</p>
    </div>
    <div class='info' id='info10'>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='4' />yes</div>
    <div><input type='radio' name='opt' value='11' />no</div>
    </div>







.info { display: none; }
.content { display: none; }

 var update = function() { 
 $(".info").hide();
 $("#info" + $(this).val()).show();
 };
 $("input[type='radio']").change(update);


 var update1 = function() { 
 $("#content" + $(this).val()).show();
 };
 $("input[type='radio']").change(update1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j2x96buL/15/

Comment: Where is yes and no in that fiddle? What should happen with no?

Comment: What values? the code in question and jsfiddle are totally different. i don't see any yes no options in fiddle.

Comment: Please stop changing the code. You are invalidating the existing answers. That's not how things work here...

Answer (score 0):

Use checkboxes instead of radios, that way you can select and deselect more than one at once.

Then, extend your function to pass the id of each form to both the hide and show functions:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#info" + val).show();
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#info" + + val).hide();
  }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j2x96buL/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am afraid I may have wasted your time as you answered to the previous version while I was editing my question...please refer to edited version above, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `HTML` structure. (*According to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacopino/j2x96buL/4/)*)

You have `.content`'s inside another. for example, `#content3` is inside `#content2`.

Your code is for hiding all `.content` and show the corresponding ones alone. But you can't see`#content3` as long as it's parent `#content2` is hidden (*for example*).

How can you show something which is inside of something hidden? [image: confused]

So you need to re-structure your `HTML` properly.

*Side note: You have multiple handlers on elements for the same event, which might result in unpredictable behaviour. You actually need only one, in which you can write all the logic:*

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
  // all the logic goes here
  // no need of a separate handler for doing something else
});
```

**Update** (*The OP keeps changing the code*)

As per the latest code, you've radio buttons with value`10`, but there are mo matching `#info10`, `#content10` etc. So nothing is displayed.

Comment: Yes  @pizzasynthesis and @T J, as I said above please accept my apologies. I am new here so I didn't realize people would answer my question as soon as I posted it so I kept debugging and editing, sorry,